# ArrayList issues: One Value Resetting all values

Tags: java, android

I have an application that contains an `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists` (`ArrayList<ArrayList<Element>>`). Basically, each element is an item that a user can interact with. Every time an element is interacted with, that element is updated and then the whole container object is resaved to the file system. One type of element (extends Element) is the `EBoolean` which can contain an element title, true or false value, and several other general parameters. When the `updateBoolean` method is called, a tab, ID, and boolean value are passed into it. The method scans for the correct element (matching IDs) and updates its value. However, I'm getting some weird behavior, modifying one element modifies every element in the entire array.

Here's the code w/ output:

```
    public void updateBoolean(int index, int ID, boolean b) {
    // Data that is gonna be saved
    System.out.println("Statistics: Index: "+index+" Array # "+elements.size()+" Elements in array #: "+elements.get(index).size());
    for (int i = 1; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("TAB " + i + " Title: " + elements.get(i).get(0).getTitle() + "Boolean value: " + ((EBoolean) elements.get(i).get(0)).getValue());
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < elements.get(index).size(); j++) {
        if (elements.get(index).get(j).getID() == ID) {
            EBoolean ent = (EBoolean) elements.get(index).get(0);
            ent.setValue(b);
            ent.setModified(true);
            elements.get(index).set(j, ent);
            System.out.println("Updated booleans, here's what we have now: ");
            for (int i = 1; i < elements.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("TAB " + i + " Title: " + elements.get(i).get(0).getTitle() + "Boolean value: " + ((EBoolean) elements.get(i).get(0)).getValue());

            }
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: Statistics: Index: 4 Array #         13 Elements in array #: 4
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 1 Title: BooleanBoolean    value: true
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 2 Title: BooleanBoolean value: false
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 3 Title: BooleanBoolean value: false
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 4 Title: BooleanBoolean value: false
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 5 Title: BooleanBoolean value: false
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 6 Title: BooleanBoolean value: false
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 7 Title: BooleanBoolean value: false
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 8 Title: BooleanBoolean value: false
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 9 Title: BooleanBoolean value: false
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 10 Title: BooleanBoolean value: false
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 11 Title: BooleanBoolean value: false
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 12 Title: BooleanBoolean value: false
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: Updated booleans, here's what we have now: 
04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 1 Title: BooleanBoolean value: true
 04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 2 Title: BooleanBoolean value: true
 04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 3 Title: BooleanBoolean value: true
 04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 4 Title: BooleanBoolean value: true
 04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 5 Title: BooleanBoolean value: true
 04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 6 Title: BooleanBoolean value: true
 04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 7 Title: BooleanBoolean value: true
 04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 8 Title: BooleanBoolean value: true
 04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 9 Title: BooleanBoolean value: true
 04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 10 Title: BooleanBoolean value: true
 04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 11 Title: BooleanBoolean value: true
 04-02 16:01:05.441 15442-15442/? I/System.out: TAB 12 Title: BooleanBoolean value: true
```

Comment: Why are you getting your `EBoolean` from `elements.get(index).get(0)` and then storing it in `elements.get(index).set(j, ent)`? Also, how are you creating the `EBoolean`s? If you do not create a new instance for each one updating one will update all the others as they are, in fact, the same. The `EBoolean` with index 0 will get updated as you take it from there and then change it. This will result in the same instance of `EBoolean` beeing in position `0` and `j` and changing either will change the other as they are the same instance of `EBoolean`.

Comment: @Leon Based on answer instances are not same as in first output value of first tab is true and others are false.

Comment: The `elements.get(index).get(0)` and then `elements.get(index).set(j, ent)` was just for testing, normally I just use one line of code for that @Leon

Comment: I solved the issue @Leon. I was not creating new instances for each new array. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New instances were not being created when added to the array. Make sure every object within the `ArrayList<ArrayList<Element>>` is its own instance.